# What's the scope of MYSQL VIEW?

Tags: mysql

I have a question concerning the scope of VIEWs. I am new to mysql and I am creating a website with automotive information.

The setup for this specific php page is that I create a VIEW from several tables in the data bank to show to the user. 
The user then has the option to filter the data to eliminate vehicles that do not fit his/hers requirements in terms of specifications. So as each filter is applied less and less vehicles are left.
This filter is applied to the original VIEW with an AJAX call that updates a section of the page.

The user has also the option to reset his choices and return to the original page selection, also with AJAX call.

So, my original VIEW for that specific user needs to remain 'live' for as long as the user is in the page.

The problem is that, hopefully, there will be many visitors at the site at the same time, visiting the same page and probably creating that same VIEW at the same time.

How does mysql works in that respect? Will the VIEW that each user creates be specific to that session, or every new CREATE VIEW from different users will overwrite the VIEW and then create a mess. In the last case, how can I avoid that problem?

The VIEW as such may not be relevant, but I am including it below just in case.

Thanks!

This from the page price_range.php:

```
mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vprice_range AS(
SELECT 
brands.brand_id,
brands.brand,
models.model_id,
models.model,
segments.segment_id,
segments.segment,
versions.version_id,
versions.version,
versions.places,
motors.power,
motors.fuel as FUELTYPE,
measures.trunk,
cost_perf.to100,
cost_perf.maxspeed,
cost_perf.emission_co2,
cost_perf.mileagemix,
images.img_path,
prices.price,
prices.tag AS TAG1,
insurance.ins_yr1,
prices.matricule AS MATRICULE,
costs.tax_ct AS TAXES,
costs.fuel_ct AS FUEL,
costs.ins_ct AS INSURANCE,
costs.maint_ct AS MAINTENANCE,
costs.total_ct as Costs5yr,
(prices.matricule)+(prices.tag)+ (insurance.ins_yr1) as CostsAcq,
warranties.wr_year,
(COUNT(trimtype)) AS safety
FROM prices
INNER JOIN insurance USING (version_id)
INNER JOIN versions USING (version_id)
INNER JOIN costs USING (version_id)
INNER JOIN versiontrim USING(version_id)
INNER JOIN trims USING(trim_id)
INNER JOIN images USING (model_id)
INNER JOIN cost_perf USING ( cp_id)
INNER JOIN measures USING (measure_id)
INNER JOIN motors USING (motor_id)
INNER JOIN models USING (model_id)
INNER JOIN segments USING (segment_id)
INNER JOIN brands USING (brand_id)
INNER JOIN warranties USING(brand_id)
WHERE price BETWEEN $low AND $high
AND trimtype IN('sec', 'help')
AND models.active='Y'
AND versions.active='Y'
GROUP BY version_id
)");
```

And then the filters that can be applied by the user, in the same price_range.php:

```
<div class="filter">
<h3>Refine your search with filter below:</h3>

<form id="filtermodel">

<p> Choose main specs:
<select id="powerselect" name="power" >
<option value="0"> cv plus que </option>
<option value="100">100 hp </option>
<option value="150">150 hp </option>
<option value="200">200 hp </option>
</select>

<select id="mileageselect" name="mileage" >
<option value="100"> Mileage moins que</option>
<option value="5">5l/100km </option>
<option value="6">6l/100km </option>
<option value="7">7l/100km </option>
</select>

<select id="co2select" name="co2" >
<option value="1000">Lower co2</option>
<option value="100"> 100 co2 </option>
<option value="150"> 150 co2 </option>
<option value="180"> 180 co2</option>
</select>

<select id="trunkselect" name="trunk" >
<option value="0">Bigger trunk </option>
<option value="300">300 l </option>
<option value="500">500 l </option>
<option value="700">700 l </option>
</select></p>
<p>Choose equipments:
<input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="115" name="hook[0]"> Leather seats
<input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="116" name="hook[1]"> Driver seat elect
<input class="hook1" type="checkbox" value="107" name="hook[2]"> Cruise control
</p>
<p> Cancel all selections: <input type="reset" id="reset" value=Reset /> </p>            
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view definition is a peristent object, like a table. The dynamic part is when you try to read data from it. Then the underlying SELECT is executed on-the-fly.

Its primary purpose is to encapsulate a complex query so that it can be used later just like a regular table, exactly the same way as a function in imperative languages. You do not create a function every time you need something done, instead you create a generic parametrised function. Depending on the situations, you then call the function with different parameters.

Unless you are creating a database administration tool, do not construct dynamic views. Instead, you may want to create this view once and for all in your database but without the *variable* `WHERE` conditions. Then use the view from your code by issuing queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM vprice_range WHERE <variable condition>
```

Comment: Thanks YaK. I believe that you are saying, applying that to my specific question, is that VIEW's are not session or used related but rather they are a feature of the data-base and each SELECT or CREATE will affect that named VIEW. Which would mean in my case that I need to rewrite my php to account for that, so that each time a filter is applied I need to transfer the original parameters of the VIEW to another php page via AJAX.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I applied the concept of the 'permanent' VIEW the way you advise, but I found that there is a time penalty compared to the 'dynamic' set up. But, in the case this should be irrelevant because IT HAS to be 'permanent.

Comment: @BernardA: it seems MySQL views are not implemented very efficiently: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

Comment: Thanks a_horse...very informative. I was actually quite surprised at the performance penalty permanent x dynamic. One would think the opposite would be true.

Comment: @BernardA I think I am beginning to understand what you are trying to do. Your users can define "search criteria", and you want to save these criteria as a view. And you are worried of these views interferring because users will typically have different search criteria. Like, appending the user's ID to the view name would address your concern. Am I right? I haven't quite answered your question, have I?

Comment: YaK that's close to it. I need the vprice_range VIEW to exist for a while for the specific user and also a couple of VIEW's in the php page called by AJAX. In the meantime after your response I was thinking that appending a variable with a random number ( or the user ID for that matter ) will address my problem. Also, because as I said before and I have confirmed in the meantime, there is a time penalty for the 'permanent' VIEW.